# Why are the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma met in this proof about decomposing a Hilbert space into invariant subspaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, set-theory

Let $H$ be a separable complex Hilbert space and let $\mathcal{A} \subset B(H)$ be an algebra of bounded linear operators on $H$ which is closed under adjoints. I've just read a very short proof that $H$ can be written as a Hilbert space direct sum of closed $\mathcal{A}$-cyclic subspaces.  Here a subspace, $V$, is $\mathcal{A}$-cyclic if there exists $v\in V$ such that $V=\overline{\mathcal{A}v}$.

The proof starts by invoking Zorn's lemma: "By Zorn's lemma, let $V$ be a closed $\mathcal{A}$-invariant subspace maximal with respect to the existence of such a decomposition."

I don't quite see how the conditions of Zorn's lemma are met, however. In particular, if $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a set of closed $\mathcal{A}$-invariant subspaces totally ordered by inclusion and if each $V_i$ can be written as a Hilbert space direct sum of $\mathcal{A}$-cyclic subspaces, why is this chain bounded above?  I feel like there are some subtleties to do with orderings.  My only thought is to maybe imbed a co-final ordinal in $I$ and use transfinite induction (???)  Or am i over thinking this?

Comment: I am only guessing, but I wonder if it's just sloppy writing. At least I would focus on the decompositions rather than the subspaces, i.e., I would look for a maximal collection of mutually orthogonal $\mathcal{A}$-cyclic subspaces instead, and let $V$ be the sum of this collection.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen  That sounds like a promising direction. thanks!

Comment: The statement isn't quite right unless "algebra" automatically implies unital, or at least nondegenerate.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Oh really? What goes wrong?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen  If you want to just copy and paste your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Your wish is my command. ☺ Anyway, to answer the other question above, it could be that every member of $\mathcal{A}$ maps $H$ onto a common proper closed subspace of $H$, and then the stated result would fail. The presence of the identity in $\mathcal{A}$ precludes that.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Right, got it. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the author was a bit sloppy in writing it up.

I would focus on the decompositions rather than the subspaces: Look for a maximal collection of mutually orthogonal $\mathcal{A}$-cyclic subspaces instead, and let $V$ be the sum of this collection.